# Python OpenCV - Align automatically an image horizontally

Tags: python, image, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

I want to find every bad pixels present in a display. A bad pixel can be a pixel with the incorrect color or if the pixel is just black. In order to do this, **i want to trace a matrix with every pixel in each cell**. To do this, **I need to align my image horizontally, so i can trace vertical and horizontally lines with no problems and get perfects rectangles to analyze.** If it possible, i would like to zoom the image so i can increase the resolution for each pixel.

This is a rotated image and as we can see, the box is not parallel with the image borders. [rotatad box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKH9l.jpg)

This is a perfectly aligned box, where the horizontally border of the box is parallel with the image borders. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dhnx2.jpg)

Once the images taken are too large, I will share a google drive shared folder with **real** examples of images.

[Display Images](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1EdG6AXmtEoyjv24bXutB1HKioRfphaTA?usp=sharing)

Can you please help me how to do this? I want to do this in Python with OpenCV.

So far, i've tried to create a zoom() function and a rotate() function, but these functions are not dynamic. Basically i need to make these functions works for every image with differents angles.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: image = cv2.rotate(src, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)